# OCI8 PECL MACOS Maverik

Tags: php, osx-mavericks, oci8

I try install OCI8 + PHP I can access mi DB's in sqlplus

I try this

```
pecl install oci8
```

and the result is this

`grep: /usr/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:
Zend Module Api No:
Zend Extension Api No:
Please provide the path to the ORACLE_HOME directory. Use 'instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/lib' if you're compiling with Oracle Instant Client [autodetect] :`

in the scrip prompt i write this

```
instantclient,/usr/local/lib
```

But i have this problem

```
/private/tmp/pear/install/oci8/oci8.c:35:10: fatal error: 'php.h' file not found
#include "php.h"
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [oci8.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Comment: Same problem here. Did you found a solution??

Answer (score 0):

You need write the instant client path.

above download link instant client:

https://www.oracle.com/br/database/technologies/instant-client/macos-intel-x86-downloads.html

Comment: Yes, use something like `--with-oci8=shared,instantclient,/Users/cjones/instantclient_19_8`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30828628)